# Build and installed OpenCV. Default install paths are different than the expected by the header files

Tags: opencv, cmake

Just built OpenCV and installed it. I am now attempting to include it's headers and am running into trouble.

Calling `cmake` without any options  yields a configuratin with
`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             /usr/local`

However, the main OpenCV header, features lines like

```
[vorac@laptop build]$ cat /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp  
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
```

The searched file is located in the parent directory, so it cannot be included:

```
[vorac@laptop build]$ ls /usr/local/include | grep core.hpp
core.hpp
motion_core.hpp
```

*What has gone wrong with the installation?*

<sub>Software used:

Fedora18

ccmake version 2.8.10.2

OpenCV commit 416fb50594003dba822a59fbc77b2d5b4e99f1a5</sub>

Comment: Have you checked that in your compiler you have pointed your code to the correct file locations? see this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) especially at the end for setting this up for MVS

Comment: @GPPK The issue here is that an OpenCV header expects other OpenCV headers to exist in a directory called "opencv2" - which they don't.  So the problem is purely with OpenCV and its installation.

Comment: @ Fraser, yup, in the stable 2.4 the headers reside in folders in $prefix/opencv2/<folders>. In the unstable *master* they are just dumped without structure in $prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have preferred to make this a comment since it's more speculation than anything else, but it's too big and it *may* help you.  So, it looks like it's probably not something you've done, more like a bug in the OpenCV cmake code.

The [commit #5170620](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/517062039e2078e86babdd87c7dfd2992e029c78#diff-1) looks like the changes to "cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake" affected the installation of include files.  If the new regex fails, the value of `${CMAKE_MATCH_1}` could be empty which means that the following line will install the module's headers to `${OPENCV_INCLUDE_INSTALL_PATH}` (which is /usr/local/include by default).

I notice that the old regex `"^(opencv2/.*)/[^/]+.h(..)?$"` has a `/` after `(opencv2/.*)` and the new one doesn't.

I'd suggest changing the line in question either to include the possibly missing `/`:

```
if(hdr2 MATCHES "^(opencv2/.*)/[^/]+.h(..)?$" AND NOT hdr2 MATCHES "opencv2/${the_module}/private.*")
```

or revert the entire line back to the previous version:

```
if(hdr2 MATCHES "^(opencv2/.*)/[^/]+.h(..)?$")
```

After that, rerun CMake and install OpenCV again.

Comment: I fixed my problem by cloning origin/2.4 - the stable branch. Master is the yet unborn 2.5. I'll try your proposal, though.

Comment: @Vorac If you try my answer and it's wrong, could you come back here and add a comment/downvote so I can delete this please?